# Ominauth broke my ruby on rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler, omniauth

After adding the gem ominauth(and ominauth-facebook) to my gemfile, I get this error when lunching my project with docker :

```
bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rails)
Bundler::GitError: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support.git (at main@528d88c) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:204:in `rescue in load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:200:in `load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/path.rb:105:in `local_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:168:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:273:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `block in index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/index.rb:11:in `build'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:268:in `index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
```

And this error on another container :

```
bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq)
Bundler::GitError: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git (at main@edb3062) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:204:in `rescue in load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:200:in `load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/path.rb:105:in `local_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/source/git.rb:168:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:273:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:271:in `block in index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/index.rb:11:in `build'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:268:in `index'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
```

Even if I remove the gem and go back to an older state of my project, it's still broken. I even tried to uninstall ruby or rvm, it did nothing.

Comment: The error message tells you to run `bundle install`. Have you done this? What was the result?

Comment: @HolgerJust
bundle install did nothing special
"Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using i18n 1.11.0
...
Bundle complete! 60 Gemfile dependencies, 151 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed."